# Stripe - after changing plan, don't bill for the new subscription until current cycle ends

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to let user to change their subscription plan. However, they won't be refunded after switching. If i set the prorate to false, stripe will bill for the new subscription right away.

For example, if the user is subscribed to a yearly plan in Jun 2018, and wants to change to monthly in Oct 2018. They will be charged with monthly plan after Jun2019, as current cycle hasn't ended yet.

How can I do with stripe api when i am updating the current subscription?

in the stripe api docs (https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update)
"if you set prorate to false when switching between different billing intervals (monthly to yearly, for example), we won't generate any credits for the old subscription's unused time—although we will still reset the billing date and will bill immediately for the new subscription."

Comment: `If i set the prorate to false, stripe will bill for the new subscription right away.` Are you sure that's true, have you tested it? The [docs say](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/prorations#disable-prorations) : `With proration disabled, the customer is billed the full amount for the new plan when the next invoice is generated. The customer is still moved to the new plan immediately, however, even though they don’t pay for the new plan until the next billing cycle.` which is the behaviour you're looking for, no?

Comment: @karllekko, i have updated the post as well. I found this in the api doc, "if you set prorate to false when switching between different billing intervals (monthly to yearly, for example), we won't generate any credits for the old subscription's unused time—although we will still reset the billing date and will bill immediately for the new subscription."

Answer (score 9):

In 2019 Stripe shipped support for Subscription Schedules which allow you to control multiple sequential phases on a Subscription. You can read more about this in the docs: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules

With this API, you can now explicitly schedule a future change of a Subscription. The idea would be to use the Create SubscriptionSchedule [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscription_schedules) a schedule from your Subscription and plan a second phase to move the Subscription to the new price on the next billing cycle.

*Past answer, which still work but less optimized:*

*One solution for this would be to follow those steps:*

- *Mark the current subscription to cancel at the end of the current period so that you don't attempt to charge that customer again.*
- *Create a new subscription to the monthly plan but put the customer on a trial period until the end of the current subscription (June 2019 in your example). This allows you to not charge him until the other subscription ends so that you switch the customer to the monthly plan as expected.*

Comment: if i put them on a trial period, won't they be able to cancel at anytime?

Comment: you are the merchant here, you control everything they do. And even if they did it does not matter really since they already paid for the full year. The other subscription on the trial is here just to kick in at the end of the yearly one

Comment: Hi @koopajah is this answer still valid?  Or is there a way to do this now?

Comment: @tank104 I just updated my answer to cover SubscriptionSchedule

Comment: @koopajah - I have the same use case - except I can't figure out how to cleanly add the "update" phase.  It's required end_date - does that just mean that the subscription PHASE ends, leaving the customer's subscription as that set by the end_date?

Comment: You don't need an `end_date` since it will be the natural end of the billing cycle itself controlled via `end_behavior`. If you choose `release` then after that second phase ends, the Subscription then continues on that Price forever (or until it gets canceled).