# STRIPE: updating user's subscription from one to the other with different billing periods

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, api, stripe-payments, payment

I was integrating stripe with the app that I am building for my company and we have a very specific use case that we have to implement. We are giving subscriptions based service to customers that can be either monthly or yearly, but the user can switch from one to the other anytime. How can we let them use the current subscription till the end of the billing_cycle and then implement the new plan? For example, if a user subscribes to yearly plan on June 1,2022 and on august 1 decides to go to monthly plan, we don't change the plan immediately, but wait till august 1, 2023 and then change to monthly plan. How do we do that in stripe?

Found this similar question, but no proper answers.
[Stripe - after changing plan, don't bill for the new subscription until current cycle ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53542264/stripe-after-changing-plan-dont-bill-for-the-new-subscription-until-current)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the similar question, you would need [Subscription Schedule](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules) for such a use case. When you customer switch from yearly plan to monthly plan on Aug 1, 2023, [create a Subscription Schedule from the current subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules/use-cases#existing-subscription) first, then configure it to have

1. 1st phase, yearly, still from June 1 2022 to June 1 2023
2. 2nd phase, monthly, starts from June 1 2023